# How to get graphs about apc info in PHP?

Tags: php, apc

I need to get statistics info like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [2bits.com](http://2bits.com/sites/2bits.com/files/apc-30mb-1.jpg))</sub>

More in [this post](https://2bits.com/articles/high-php-execution-times-drupal-and-tuning-apc-includeonce-performance.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take apc.php from APC distro and open it in browser.